# Explaining why false and modulus always equate true in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a question that I kind of know the answer for but I can't sum up in words (I think the best way of saying that is "I don't know why"). I'm putting together a simple test for my Junior Developers (they are very Junior) like so...

Write a function called fooBar that takes an argument

1. If the argument is a multiple of 3 return "foo"
2. If the argument is a multiple of 5 return "Bar"
3. If the argument is a multiple of 3 and 5 return "fooBar"
4. Otherwise return the original argument

I'd hope for or expect an answer like so:

```
function fooBar (n) {

    if ((n % 3 === 0) && (n % 5 === 0)) {
        return "fooBar";
    } else if (n % 3 === 0)  {
        return "foo";
    } else if (n % 5 === 0) { 
        return "Bar";
    } else {
        return n;
    }
}
```

all is good but I want to trip up or trick the Juniors as the function will work or seem logical in all the following cases below except for one

```
fuzzBuzz(3); // returns "foo"
fuzzBuzz(5); // returns "Bar"
fuzzBuzz(15); // returns "fooBar"
fuzzBuzz(true); // returns true
fuzzBuzz(false); // returns "fooBar"
fuzzBuzz(function(){return true;}); // returns "function anonymous()"
```

when we pass `false` we get an unexpected result as `(false % 3 === 0)` and `(false % 5 === 0)` equate to `true`. I expect this... I just can't explain why, can anyone put into words why we get this strange behaviour, I used to put it down to the "quirks" of Javascript!

Comment: I assume (hence comment not answer) that `%` coerces `false` to a number, which would be 0.  The logic then follows correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [EMCA Script 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) standard, section 11.5, it specifies that both operands to a multiplicative operator are converted to numbers. The `%` operator is considered a multiplicative operator.

The numeric conversion is specified in [section 9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) which states that when booleans are converted:

> The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false.

Therefore, `(n % 3 === 0) && (n % 5 === 0)` is true and the function returns `fooBar`.

Comment: That's the part of the spec I didn't have time to find :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use false in any arithmetic expression. It evaluates to 0.

```
alert(false +0 );  // this gives 0
```

So `false%3 ==0` evaluates to true.

Similarly `true` evaluates to 1

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cfmudsrv/)

Answer (score 1):

As true always is converted to 1 and false is converted to 0, then when you pass false you should get **fooBar** with this condition: `n % 3 === 0`, and when you pass true none of condition are not true, So true itself returned

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ms3jfun4/)